# how can java visual VM get connection to eclipse java task

Tags: java, visualvm

I want to use java VisualVM to monitor the performance of my JAVA APP, but Java VisualVM can not get the detail data of the java task of eclipse. what should I do for this? is any one know?
[image]

Comment: Can you select the eclipse process? Which data are you missing?

Comment: thank you for you reply, the pid 7852 is my eclipse, but VisualVM can not get the information of the VM in eclipse, you can see, it show "Local Application(pid 7852)", but no more information(CPU usage, Memory usage...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` in the vmargs of Eclipse.

You can find out whether you have looking in this dialog: Help -> About -> Installation Details -> Configuration.

`eclipse.vmargs=...` shows all the arguments which were passed for the Java VM.

If this option is missing, then open `eclipse.ini` and search for the line `-vmargs`. If it's not there, add it at the end:

```
  -vmargs
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
```

Note that each of these options should go on a different line.

Make sure that `-vmargs` is the last Eclipse option in the file; everything below will be assembled into an array of arguments to the VM and ignored by Eclipse.