# Eclipse not noticing changes to eclipse.ini?

Tags: eclipse

I have had a problem lately with `jvisualvm` not allowing me to take heap dumps and showing very little information at all. I believe [this is my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924817/how-can-java-visual-vm-get-connection-to-eclipse-java-task).

I made the suggested changes to `eclipse.ini`. It currently looks like this:

[image: my eclipse.ini file]

The line in question here is then line 19.

Now, when I check the configuration in Eclipse, the new option doesn't show up.

[image: eclipse conf window]

I have restarted Eclipse twice, both via `File -> Restart` and closing and re-opening, with no effect. Also, I have changed the order of the options in the file, with no effect.

What might cause this and can this be fixed somehow?

**EDIT:** I also tried closing Notepad++ and then restarting. No effect. `type` in the command prompt still shows the changes, so they are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by running Eclipse in clean mode, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2030092/1938435).

1. I ran Eclipse from the command prompt:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse>eclipse -clean
   ```

   This can be done in other ways also, as seen the answer linked above.

   **At this point, the problem is solved. The rest of the steps are what happened.**
2. I had to choose my workspace again, as the cache had been cleared.
3. Package Explorer failed to load.
4. After one more restart, everything worked fine.

Comment: Even years later this answer still holds true.